# BASH if - if nothing provided

Tags: bash, shell, unix, makefile

I am trying to perform a task only if a certain file type exists - so I have this

```
if [ -e  `find /directory -type f -name "*.filetype" | head -1`];
      then ...
```

this was always evaluating true (even if no filetype like this exists - I eventually realized that this:

```
if [ -e ]
```

evaluates as true (i.e. if nothing is given - which happens when my condition did not find the filetype) - Does anyone know what I should be doing to get what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line would have been correct with

```
if [ -n "`find /directory -type f -name '*.filetype'`" ] ;
```

`-n` tests for non-empty strings.

As noted in the comments, the backtick syntax is deprecated in favor of the `$()` syntax.

Comment: What version of find returns non-zero for a valid query with no results?

Comment: @glennjackman hum I mixed up things in my head. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This doesn't work for the same reason the original doesn't: `[ -n ]` returns true, because when the `[` command sees only a single item ("-n"), it checks to see if it's nonblank and returns true if it is. In other words, with it's treating "-n" as a string to be tested rather than an operator. The solution is to double-quote the command substitution part: `if [ -n "$(find ... head -1)" ]; then` -- note that I've used `$()` instead of backquotes because the syntax is a bit cleaner, and also that the space before `]` is required.

Comment: I don't see why @Janos' answer would be better.  This is POSIX compatible, simple, and straightforward.

Comment: @damienfrancois 1. you left a single backtick in there, without closing it. 2. Since `$()` is favored, why not write it that way? 3. the `-n` is unnecessary: non-empty strings are "true", empty strings are "false".

Comment: @tripleee how is mine worse?

Comment: @janos I like yours too but it's not portable.

Comment: @tripleee why not portable? If you explain I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: `[[` is a Bashism, so not available in POSIX sh / dash etc.

Answer (score 3):

I learned this technique recently:

```
if [[ $(find /directory -type f -name "*.filetype" 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

- We redirect stderr to `/dev/null` to hide any error messages
- The output of `find` will be non-blank if the file matched both conditions, otherwise it will be blank.
- The `[[ ... ]]` evaluates to true or false if the output of find is non-blank or blank, respectively.

I used a different version before:

```
if find /directory -type f -name "*.filetype" 2>/dev/null | grep -q .; then
    ...
fi
```

but this is less good, because it uses an extra `grep` process. The first solution achieves the same with a single `find` process.

Comment: Is there no risk at all that `$(find ...)` evaluates to something that is false or that raises an error? I tested with files named `'1 == 2'` and `'&&'` and it worked ok, but I wonder if there is no risk at all.

Comment: @damienfrancois, in bash inside `[[ ... ]]`, variables are *not* subject to word-splitting, so this construct will only check the string length of the output.

Comment: Here's the manual reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b